# Games that account for colourblind

Tags: steam, xbox-360, ps3, ps4, xbox-one

What games have an option for people with colourblindness to play?

Comment: many many many ***many*** games do this nowadays. Listing them all would be near impossible

Comment: I'm sorry but these kind of questions are off-topic here (for multiple reasons: way too broad to properly answer, any answer should be a neverending constantly updating list, and it is basically requesting all games who fit for a criterium, and that's off-topic too.

Comment: @Rapitor And that explains quite well why we don't allow these types of questions.  There is no right answer.

Comment: " [...] site policies prohibit questions of the following types: [...]
Catalogues (listing games that fit specific criteria or are like an existing game)" from http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: All good. First question.

Answer (score 2):

As of COD4, the series has colorblind options, WoW's latest patch also accounts. Also Borderlands 2's next update will have an option too.